# Visual studio templating system

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, visual-studio, theming

I am doing web development in ASP.NET.

Is there some way to load different page designs depending on who lands on your page.

So I want to create a sort of template system where I offer a selection of templates for a page and the user selects what one they want.

Is there some built in functionality for this or is there any plug-ins I can use?

Thanks

Comment: @sinni800 C# + visual-studio = asp.net...

Comment: @AndreaTurri Not quite... I wasn't even sure if he actually means web-development.

Comment: @Reniuz also HTML is missing in the equation, if you want to go like this.

Comment: You question is not clear. Talking about VS and pages, what are you really want to change? WEB page template or VS theme or else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the built in ASP.NET functionality called "theming"

Here's a tutorial on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcsbskx7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to change the ASP.NET site template or the stylesheet? If it's the latter, let's say your main stylesheet is embedded like so:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/Site.css" />
```

Add an ID to the tag, such as id="style". Then in the code-behind you could do the following (I've used a button in this example but perhaps a DropDownList control would be the best, which you could populate with stylesheets found in a certain directory):

```
 protected void BtnStyle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    HtmlLink Link = FindControl("style") as HtmlLink;

    if (Link.Href.Equals("Styles/Site.css"))
        Link.Href = "Styles/Site2.css";
    else
        Link.Href = "Styles/Site.css";
  }
```

As for changing the site template programmatically, I have no experience, but I imagine that it's possible.